# Answer delete votes tooltip was copy/pasted from the question delete votes tooltip

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, user-interface, tooltips

[image: muahahhahaha says Jeff]

<sup>(Click for source post.)</sup>

Note: this only occurs over the *number*, not the text "delete".

Comment: Related: [Feature request: every time a SE employee uses Ctrl+V, reduce their salary by 10%](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/-1/no-this-isnt-real-geez)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While we're sometimes guilty of copy/paste [shenanigans](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-oWWbAqSHcE), this is a case of just not differentiating on post type in a string format statement.

A fix will be pushed in the next build.